# I can't pass a variable through the include statement

Tags: php, html

I'm just starting with PHP and I'm doing a sign-up form that passes the information to the register.php file and then the script in that file checks if the password field value equals the confirm password field value field then if they aren't equal, it sets a certain value to the $message variable and then redirects to the index.php file and where that $messege variable should be echoed in a p tag but isn't printed then

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <p>
    It's free and only takes a minute!
  </p>
  <div>
    <p class="error">
      <!--here is the $messege variable -->
      <?php
          include 'register.php';
          echo $messege;
          ?>
    </p>
  </div>
  <form class="form" action="register.php" method="post">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email"><br>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <label>Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
    <span>By clicking the sign up button you
                agree to our <a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a> and <a href="terms.html">Privacy policy</a> </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

and this the register.php file

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
  $from_email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
  if ($password == $confirm_password) {
    $messege = null;
      header("Location: index.php?Succesful");
  } else {
    $messege = "Password and Confirm-Password doesn't match";
    header("Location: index.php?error-in-password");
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: if you call `header` after generating any output ( as you are doing here ) you need to enable [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: The page that calls `include 'register.php';` - is that the `index.php` page? If it is the variable $message will not be available after the redirect as it is defined inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Comment: `$message` will never be defined outside of your `register.php` since you only define it if the form was posted and then redirect the user away after defining the variable (which means the variable will be discarded when the redirect happens). Also, you need to put your header()-calls before you output anything

Comment: I tried to put a variable called $test outside the if statement with a fixed value and then recall it in the index.php file and this also doesn't work

Comment: Your PHP scripts only “live” for the duration of the _current_ request. When you redirect, the browser makes a _new_ request, and any variables you had in your script instances that run on the previous request, do not exist any more. You either need to pass your values as GET parameters, or put them into a _session_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because in the register.php you first check

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

but there is not post request and only you have access to $_GET['error-in-password']

so for the echo the message in page you need to

```
header("Location: index.php?error-in-password&message=$message");
```

and in your register.php you need to

```
if (isset($_GET['error-in-password']))
{
    echo $_GET['message'];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the message before adding it as a query param and to pass the message through [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when outputting the data (to protect against XSS attacks)